# List of Expired Merge Subscribers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

I have a setup of merge replication.

Sometimes, subscribers will not be able to sync within the retention period set in the publication.

How can I get a list of expired subscribers to a merge replication?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. expand instance of SQL server
3. expand Replication Folder
4. expand Local Publications
5. Right click publication that you want to check for any expired subscriptions and choose 'Launch Replication Monitor'
6. expand My publishers, right click on publisher in question and click 'Configure replication alerts'
7. Choose 'Replication Warning: Subscription expiration (threshold: expiration) and click Configure
8. select Response and check Notify Operator
9. Add new operator

This will alert you when you have expired subscriptions. It will show all expired subscriptions in Replication Monitor on the Subscription Watch List Tab. If you set it up correctly, will also give you email alerts.

EDIT:

In order for you to receive emails, database mail must be configured.

1. Connect to instance
2. expand the management folder in object explorer
3. right click on Database Mail and choose configure database mail
4. add profile name and click Add to configure email address and email server

   - if you don't have an email server you can use google / yahoo /etc.

Hope this helps!!

[image]

[image]